# TypeError: '_csv.reader' object is not callable

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Hello i am a relative beginner and am scraping a Website. I want to use the urls out of a csv file to scrape a Website but i am failing miserably at it. every time i execute my spider this error occurs TypeError: '_csv.reader' object is not callable

```
class RandomspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'randomspider'

    def start_requests(self):
        l = open('/home/ubuntu/Desktop/random.csv')
        data = csv.reader(l)
        for urls in data():
           start_urls = [data]
```

Update:1

```
def start_requests(self):
            l = open('/home/ubuntu/Desktop/doctors.csv')
            data = csv.reader(l)
            start_urls = [data]
```

Comment: Just iterate over `data` itself, without calling it: `for urls in data:`

Comment: thanks but now i get TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: I don't think you're getting that at the same place. Is your "Update:1" your try at implementing what I said? If so, you're doing it wrong. You still need the for loop, just not the parens.

Comment: ahh thanks sorry im still new to this

Answer (score 1):

You're getting this error because of the line
`for urls in data():`.

The problem is that you want to iterate over the `data` object, but you're actually telling Python to call it as if it were a function by doing `data()`.

Your code should be more along the lines of:

```
for url in data:
    # Do stuff here
```